Ubuntu 20.04.6 is unable to use multiple monitors
I'm facing hard times trying to configure my two Display Port monitors into my PC. I have a Dell Optiflex Micro Plus 7010 computer with three Display Port connectors, but only one is working after I install Ubuntu 20.04. My computer has an Intel UHD Graphics 770. When I install Ubuntu 22.04.3 both display port monitors works normally.
The main thing is that the computed is running graphics with llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits) when I install Ubuntu 20.04, but when I run Ubuntu 22.04 it runs as graphics Mesa Intel Graphics RLP-5.
I spent the last days trying to make two monitors with Ubuntu 20.04, but without success. I'm starting to think that it may be an compatibility problem between Ubuntu 20.04.6 and my hardware.
I tried to use the terminal to map monitor, update my Intel Drivers and force my second display port to work. I also tried to change monitors and display port, but it didn't work.
